# How we use Connection pooling with Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, database-connection, threadpool, c3p0

Is there a thread pool library like c3po , dbcp for Mongodb connection pools? As hibernate uses c3po for connection polling can we use c3po with mongodb ? Thanks in advance

Regards

Comment: its automatically done my monogdriver but you need to connect using same connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use a separate thread pool library as the Java MongoDB driver provides its own connection pooling by default.

See the details in [the docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/java-concurrency/).

Comment: I don't want to use default MonoDB connection pooling and want to use c3po as hibernate uses. Can it possible or some other third party library available which can gave support for connection olling with MongoDB